# How to use FullCalendar goToDate in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am working on a react app that shows the AppointmentList (which is a component) as a daily calendar view using the FullCalendar package. When I call the component AppointmentList, I pass in a parameter: some date. I want to use the FullCalendar goToDate function to go the date that I am getting in as a parameter. I tried using the ref and calendarApi but it doesn't work.

this is how my AppointmentList component looks for now

```
const AppointmentList = ({ click }) => {
  const arr = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'event 1',
      start: '2023-03-02T10:00:00',
      end: '2023-03-02T12:00:00',
    },
  ]
  console.log(click)

  const calendarRef = useRef(null)
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date())

  const handleDateChange = ({ click }) => {
    setDate({ click })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    calendarRef.current.getApi().gotoDate(date)
  }, [date])

  return (
    <Box>
      <FullCalendar
        ref={calendarRef}
        dateClick={(info) => handleDateChange(info.date)}
        plugins={[timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
        initialView="timeGridDay"
        events={arr}

      />
    </Box>
  )
}

export default AppointmentList
```

How can I have FullCalendar to go to the 'click' date?

EDIT:

This is how my page looks. I want the calendar view to change when the buttons (today, < > ) above are clicked. That value is given to my component as a parameter. I am sure the value gets passed to my component because I see it change when I do console.log(click) but the issue is that it doesn't change the calendar view

[image]

Comment: `I tried using the ref and calendarApi but it doesn't work`...in what way? we can't fix "doesn't work". All we can do is point you to the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/react), which it sounds like you have probably read already. Show what you tried, and explain what error you got. You can [edit] your post. See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue. Thanks.

Comment: I apologize for that. I have added the code that I tried and doesn't change the date

Comment: Thanks. It occurs to me that if you're doing this based on the dateClick event being triggered, then the date you clicked on is already visible on the calendar, so of course, navigating to it won't do anything, because you can already see it!

Comment: Are you actually trying to make it change the view from (for example) month to day view when the date is clicked? And also, why not just use the [built-in navigation links](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/date-nav-links)?

Comment: This is a group project where my part is to get the date from other team and change the day view to that particular date. And they are not using FullCalendar so all I have is a date prop from them that I need to integrate in my code. I will add a picture of the page looks and what I am trying to do

Comment: `I want the calendar view to change when the buttons (today, < > ) above are clicked`...those buttons look like they are part of fullcalendar, so the date should change automatically when they are clicked. That seems to be unrelated to what you asked originally. Unless for some strange reason you made your own versions of these buttons instead of the ones fullcalendar provides?

Comment: `they are not using FullCalendar so all I have is a date prop from them that I need to integrate in my code`...how are you receiving that, then? The only interaction shown in your code is the `dateClick={(info) => handleDateChange(info.date)}` bit, as far as I can see. Hence my comment that trying to set date via dateClick won't do anything useful.